# phonegap build, connection plugin to check network connection

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am developing an HTML/CSS/JS app with Phonegap Build (using phonegap 2.9.0) and I am trying to check the network connection of the device.

I included the plugin in the config.xml file like this :

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
```

But when I compile on Phonegap Build I get :

```
plugin unsupported: org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

Can you help me figure this out?
I am not sure I want to updgrade to phonegap version 3.0.0 because it doesn't support Blackberry...

Comment: could anyone answer this ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that Phonegap 2.9.0 doesn't need to load this plugin, like other core plugins : 
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_build_plugin_unsupported_org_apache_cordova_network_information?rfm=1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a plugin. Providing you are creating this app in HTML5 and Javascript, you can simply call the function:

```
if navigator.onLine; <!--PERFORM A FUNCTION--> else;
```

Read more on it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_online.asp

Worked for me on my phone gap build.